# ASP.NET Core MVC - Razor - asp-action route issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am having a small issue with routing when creating a form and setting its route in razor. I have the following in my view:

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Lead">
```

However, it POSTs data to my API endpoint (`api/lead/create`) instead of my standard Controller (`lead/create`).

It generates the following HTML:

```
<form action="/api/lead/create" method="post">
```

Any suggestions to how this can be resolved? My controller routes are the default:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

If I completely remove my API method, then it picks the correct route and things work as expected, but I can't seem to have both?

I am at a loss to this one..

EDIT:

This are the Lead Controller definitions:

```
// GET: Lead/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var viewModel = new CreateOrUpdateLeadViewModel();

    return View(viewModel);
}

// POST: Lead/Create
[Route("lead/create")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

And this is the definition for the Lead method on the API Controller:

```
[Route("api/lead/create", Name = "apileadcreate")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] LeadDto leadDto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the route name for your MVC controller too:

```
[Route("lead/create", Name = "leadcreate")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] LeadDto leadDto)
```

and use this syntax for form:

```
<form asp-route="leadcreate" method="post">
    <!-- Input and Submit elements -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said,`asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Lead"` will generate to `action="/api/lead/create"`.I think you can try to use

```
<form action="/lead/create" method="post">
```

So that you can make sure it will not go to `/api/lead/create`